# Altering fields via return values vs. altering fields by referencing them within methods?

Tags: java, performance, methods, field, parameter-passing

Let's say I have a private integer x as a field in class Example, and I want to set this integer to 1. There are two ways I am going about doing this at the moment:

```
//Choice 1
public class Example{

    private int x;

    // Class Constructor
    public Example(){

        x = setX();

    }

    private int setX(){

        return 1;

    }

}

//Choice 2
public class Example{

    private int x;

    // Class Constructor
    public Example(){

        setX();

    }

    private void setX(){

        x = 1;

    }

}
```

I was wondering which way is optimal in terms of space and time, or if it matters at all. If the difference is negligible, which way is best practice?

In the same sense, when I want a method to utilize a class field, is it better to pass that field as a parameter or just reference it within the method?

Comment: The best practice is to initialize class attributes in the constructor as follow `x=1`.

Comment: I shouldn't have named the function setX as it is a bit misleading to my question; I'm rather concerned about any methods that change a class field in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the last part of your question: methods of an object have access to the state of the object. Passing it as argument is unnecessary.

Regarding the first part: the biggest problem with the alternatives you show is not really which one to choose. The biggest problem is the naming.

A method called `setX()` is expected to set the value of x. And a Java developer would expect such a setter to take a parameter. A method called `setX()` that doesn't set anything but returns a computed value should rather be called `getSomeValue()` or `computeSomeValue()`.

Comment: I see what you are saying. The names I chose were to keep it as simple as possible, but given any method that acts to change a field variable and is not a setter, is there an optimal choice?

Comment: If the method computes a single field value, I'd prefer the first solution: it makes it easier to test this method, to extract it to another class, to reuse it in another context, or to initialize another field.